# Looking to create a map for a county similar to the Indicators of Broadband Need map by the NTIA in R

Tags: r, geom

https://broadbandusa.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=e2b4907376b548f892672ef6afbc0da5

Looking to create a map similar to this one in R for a county. I have the shapefiles for each (FCC, ACS, and Ookla), but when I try to create a new fill for a new object, the old fill gets overwritten. Is there a way to plot three different datasets and have a legend for each?

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the code you are using for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.